# Doing .diff() on pandas column(s) gives wrong output?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to take the difference of a column using `.diff()` in a dataframe with a date column and a value column.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Date':['11/11/2011', '11/12/2011', '11/13/2011'], 'a': [2, 3,4]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df1.diff(axis = 1)
```

Pandas gives me this output:

```
        Date    a
0   11/11/2011  2
1   11/12/2011  3
2   11/13/2011  4
```

Which is the df1 and not the difference where I expect the output to be:

```
        Date    a
0   11/11/2011  NaN
1   11/12/2011  1
2   11/13/2011  1
```

Comment: When you said *"take the difference of a column using `.diff()` in a dataframe with a date column and a value column"*, it's unclear whether you wanted a columnwise diff of **the entire dataframe** or **just the date column**. I edited your title but please fix it as needs. pandas has both [`DataFrame.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) and [`Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) methods, but you'll notice Series.diff()` doesn't need an `axis=1` argument

Comment: Just do `df1['a'].diff()`.

Comment: @MayankPorwal: telling the OP to diff a single column before they've clarified whether they want to diff the entire dataframe (column-wise) doesn't make this question clear or a reusable resource for other users.

Comment: I just posted my comment based on his sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.set_index('Date').diff(axis = 0) saves the day
```

Comment: Still giving me the same output. Doesn't do the difference operation

Answer (score -1):

`axis=1` means you are subtracting columns not rows. Your target result is related to rows. Use `axis=0` instead.
Second, it is not correct to do subtractions over strings. It will throw an error since python does not support that.

Comment: How would I change it to a form so python can do that?